# VMware - restart Linux vm without losing everything on it

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, persistence

I have a Linux VM that has frozen completely. It likely happened because I left it idle for too long. I don't have any snapshots and I don't want to have to set it up again due to having a lot of issues getting everything up and running. When I run a Windows vm on it I can restart it and have it reload as a normal computer. If I shut down a Linux, though, it is completely reset and nothing is saved.

Is it possible to restart the Linux VM somehow without losing all my data, configurations, installed programs etc? I am on VMware Workstation 15 pro

I installed from a Linux ISO the same way I install Windows VM. I did not remove the installation medium from the drive before rebooting,  I can't remove it either because it's in use by VMware. If I remove the ISO then the screen is just black after powered on.

Comment: It sounds like you're booting up a live system instead of a proper installation. Is that the case? This seems to be an XY problem (Linux has no issues rebooting).

Comment: I don't know, I installed from a Linux iso the same way I install Windows vm. Now that I'm in this mess, is there a way to get out of it? @Panki

Comment: ... did you remove the installation medium from the drive before rebooting?

Comment: Nope, it's still there. I can't remove it either because it's in use by vmware

Comment: Well, duh! Windows would do the same if you kept booting from its installation medium.

Comment: @JohnDoe, please provide which Linux distribution you "installed"... so we can help you better...

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually *install* Linux on to the VM, rather than just booting into the *Live version*.

A live version is non-persistent, meaning that any changes made will be lost upon reboot, i.e. programs installed, data/files created.

You need to run through the whole install process, that will take 5-10 minutes. Once installed, then you can remove the installation medium and reboot the VM, as one would normally do. Then any changes made thereafter will be persistent.

If you are using Ubuntu, see [ubuntu live-usb doesn't save settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/283160/348964).